# HTML Javascript function not defined

Tags: javascript, html, exception

As the title states, I have an issue where my HTML file is not finding a function in a javascript file, even though the javascript file is added and loaded in the `<head>`.

The code in the HTML file

In `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascripts/num.js"></script>
```

In the `<body>`:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="firstName"></input>
<input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="lastName"></input>
<script>
function start() {
readNames();
}
</script>
<input class="btn btn-github" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="start();" id="calculate"></input>
```

In num.js:

```
function readNames() {
  firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  alert(firstName);
  lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  alert(lastName);
}
```

Comment: As given, that will work. Look in the web console for errors, such as with the path to `num.js`. Ensure that in `num.js`, the function declaration you've shown is a global scope (outside of all other functions), since you're relying on it being a global.

Comment: Check if `num.js` directory is in right location.

Comment: have you created start and readNames function in the `javascripts/num.js`

Comment: Just to be sure, are you getting a "readNames is not defined" or a "readNames is not a function" error?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder It is in the right position, no errors on position of javascript file. The function start() is defined in the html doc as its own script.

Comment: @Teemu The browser console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: readNames is not defined "

Comment: @afroraydude: Not `start`, `readNames`. You're relying on it being a global.

Comment: If there are no errors causing by num.js before the function definition and that function really is defined in the global scope, the only possible reason is, that the file is not loaded (or you've a typo in its name).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that second sentance was ment for Khurram Ali, sorry.

Comment: @Teemu How could I fix that?

Comment: At first you can check the Net(work) tab at dev tools, you can see if the script is actually loaded. If it's not, you've to check the URL in `src` and the saving folder to see that the file really is saved on the given path. The script might be loaded from the cache, in that case it might not be the latest version you have. Server delivers a wrong MIME type?

Comment: @Teemu I doubt. According to the browser, the current version of both files have been loaded. I don't know about server-side. I can't go into the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see is that you're not enclosing your javascript function definition with  like this:

```
<script>
function readNames() { 
    firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
      alert(firstName);
      lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
      alert(lastName);
}
</script>
```

From the code I see, I would take out the start(); function as it just calls readNames(). In your onclick event, call readNames();

If you continue to have problems, try inserting "event" in the function definition, like this: readNames(event);, and when you call it: onclick="readNames(event)".

Firebug can help solve problems with javascript, with [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/). To use it, download the extension in either Firefox or Chrome (I prefer Firefox), and hit F12. When you enter something in the textboxes and click submit, does it give you any error messages?

Comment: The script is within a _.js file_, it can't contain HTML.

Comment: Why would I put `<script>` and `<script>` thing around the code if the .js file is external?

Comment: My bad, misread that. Still, I've been able to solve most js problems I've had in the past by using the F12 developer tools.

Comment: In Chrome, you can hit ctrl + shift + i to bring up developer tools also

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply call the click event within the JS file :

```
function readNames() {
firstName = document.getElementById("firstName").value;
  alert(firstName);
  lastName = document.getElementById("lastName").value;
  alert(lastName);
}
document.getElementById("calculate").onclick=function(){readNames()};
```

and remove the onclick attribute :)

Comment: what kind of error cause this worked fine : 
https://jsfiddle.net/jsfiddle_wahabi_zakaria/fL6dsbgs/